# Trouble with uploading file into my express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

I want to send message to my express server with some file attachments. I trying to do that by sending AJAX request with FormData. But something goes wrong: there is no any data in req.body.

This is my client-side code:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('message', $('.message-input').html());

$.ajax({
  url: '/api/sendMessage',
  data: formData,
  method: 'post',
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function(response){
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

This is my server-side code:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/api/sendMessage', function(req, res){
    console.log("req.body:" + req);
    res.send('success');
});
```

And it outputs nothing: `req.body: {}`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need something to parse multipart form data.

Try https://github.com/expressjs/multer

Comment: Are you sure? I thought that multer is used just for uploading files, not for accept FormData.

Comment: @ДенисТерещенко `multer` is meant to parse `multipart/form-data` (which _may_ include file uploads, but also regular form fields)